# Modal dialog doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've made a modal with the help of javascript. How come the modal doesn't come out? These are my codes:

```
 <button class="jobview-control btn-primary jobview-btn"  id="btn-show-modal">Recommend</button>

    <div class="modal hide" id="dialog-box">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>body body body</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <p>this is the Footer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $("#btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             $("#dialog-box").modal('show');
         });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: This could be the result of anything. Are you properly referencing your javascript files? Use your browser developer tools for any errors and post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your button the following two attributes `data-target="#dialog-box"` and `data-toggle="modal"` and it will work :

```
<button data-target="#dialog-box" data-toggle="modal" class="jobview-control btn-primary jobview-btn" id="btn-show-modal" >Recommend</button>
```

Hope this helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button data-target="#dialog-box" class="jobview-control btn-primary jobview-btn" id="btn-show-modal" data-toggle="modal">Recommend</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="dialog-box">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>body body body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <p>this is the Footer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,, i tried your code but the background only turns darker,... but the dialog didnt come out :( whats wrong with this?

Comment: hey.... i changed the class "modal hide" into "modal fade" and it worked! hahahahaa THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we are talking about a Bootstrap modal. If so, try with this:

```
<button type="button" class="jobview-control btn-primary jobview-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog-box">Recommend</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="dialog-box" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>body body body</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <p>this is the Footer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No need for jQuery, because you specify in the button (`data-target`) what to open on click.

Comment: i tried it sir... but still doesnt work :(

Comment: See my updated answer.